# Unable to login into Workbench for any of my Sandboxes

Tags: workbench, access

Getting an error when trying to connect to a Sandbox with Workbench.

[image]

Comment: Did you follow the link in the warning banner and ensure that you followed the instructions [there to create a Connected App](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/wiki/Using-Workbench-in-Your-Org)?

Comment: It's a known issue:  https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/issues/824

Answer (score 1):

It was a known issue: https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/issues/824

Looks to be resolved now.